# Why doen't Rails check 'GET' request with csrf_token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think that rails prevent someone from Hijacking session and fixation if 'GET' request is checked with csrf_token.
I think that if token doesn't match, session must be deleted,but not reset.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

NO, get request is not supposed modify any data on the server, it just get some information, so it's a safe operation, no need for token verification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think if get request is verified it prevents from hijacking and fixation session.If attacker steals user's session,attacker's token is different from user's.right?